# Running openssl commands in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, command

I'm executing the following command in PowerShell:

```
Invoke-Expression "openssl pkcs12 -in $certCN.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out $certCN.key -password pass:1111"
```

It works fine, however the output from `openssl` is causing ugly console errors:

```
openssl : MAC verified OK
At line:1 char:1
+ openssl pkcs12 -in www.mywebsite.com.pfx -nocerts -node ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MAC verified OK:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

What's the best way to execute this OpenSSL command and have the output ignored or at least not interpreted as a command?

Comment: How is trying to get a powershell script to run without errors *NOT* a programming question again?

Answer (score 13):

You don't need `Invoke-Expression` (in fact, [it's not recommended](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) except in specific cases because it is susceptible to injection). Just run the command and quote the parameters where you need variable string expansion:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in "$certCN.pfx" -nocerts -nodes -out "$certCN.key" -password pass:1111
```

To ignore the output of the command, one common technique is to pipe to `Out-Null`.

Comment: Thank you - Not very familiar with powershell.  I was planning on reading up tomorrow on invoke-expression vs. invoke-command.  I'll give this a go.

Comment: Thanks. I've read up on them and see how they are pointless and risky.  Also, FYI - I tried piping these commands to Out-Null and it didn't work.  However appending the command with 2>&1 did. Thank you again.

Comment: `Out-Null` doesn't redirect stderr, IIRC.

Comment: using `| Out-Null` on this command suppresses only part of the output. there is still some output that is interpreted as an error.... any more ideas?

Comment: Where do you get `openssl` binaries from safely in case you don't want to build from source?

Comment: @user3613932 If you have Git installed, you already have it at C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe